# MySQL "Sending data" horribly slow

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a modest-sized table, 277k records at the moment, which I am trying to do a `FULLTEXT` search on.  The search seems to be very quick until it gets to the Sending data phase.

**The Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `sqinquiries_inquiry` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ts` datetime NOT NULL,
  `names` longtext NOT NULL,
  `emails` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `sqinquiries_inquiry_search` (`names`,`emails`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=305560 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**The Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `sqinquiries_inquiry` WHERE (
  MATCH (`sqinquiries_inquiry`.`names`) AGAINST ('smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR
  MATCH (`sqinquiries_inquiry`.`emails`) AGAINST ('smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) ORDER BY `sqinquiries_inquiry`.`id` DESC LIMIT 100
```

**The Profile:**  (I snipped out seemingly useless info)

```
+-------------------------+----------+
| Status                  | Duration |
+-------------------------+----------+
| preparing               | 0.000014 | 
| FULLTEXT initialization | 0.000015 | 
| executing               | 0.000004 | 
| Sorting result          | 0.000008 | 
| Sending data            | 2.247934 | 
| end                     | 0.000011 | 
| query end               | 0.000003 | 
+-------------------------+----------+
```

The `DESCRIBE` looks great, a simple one liner:
**The Describe:**

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: sqinquiries_inquiry
type: index
possible_keys: NULL
key: PRIMARY
key_len: 4 
ref: NULL
rows: 100
Extra: Using where
```

So what I don't understand is where the 2.25 seconds of Sending data is coming from?  I'm seeing similar performance in Python and in the console `mysql` app, both connecting to `localhost`.

**Updates:**

- Per comment requesting the average row size, it is:  53.8485
- Per comment, here is the `DESCRIBE` above.

Comment: how big is the amount of data you're retrieving? if you don't know, then look at the table statistics and tell us the average row size.

Comment: Wasn't sure how to figure out the average row size, so I threw the output of this up there:  `SELECT AVG(LENGTH(names) + LENGTH(emails) + LENGTH(id) + LENGTH(ts)) as avg_length from sqinquiries_inquiry`.  If there is a better way, please let me know.

Comment: The problem is that your `FULLTEXT KEY` is not used. Could you please post the `DESCRIBE`?

Comment: Right, your `FULLTEXT KEY` is not used, the `PRIMARY KEY` is used for sorting instead. Rewrite the query as in my post.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> The `DESCRIBE` looks great, a simple one liner.

Since you are using only one table in your query it cannot be anything other than a one-liner.

However, your query does not use the `FULLTEXT` index.

For the index to be usable, you should rewrite the query a little:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sqinquiries_inquiry
WHERE   MATCH (names, emails) AGAINST ('smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY
        id DESC
LIMIT 100
```

`MATCH` only uses the index if the you match against the exact set of columns the index is defined on.

So your query uses the index scan on `id`: `Using index; Using where` at the very end of your `DESCRIBE`.

`Sending data` is quite misleading: this is actually time elapsed between the end of the previous operation and the end of the current operation.

For instance, I just ran this query:

```
SET profiling = 1;

SELECT  *
FROM    t_source
WHERE   id + 1 = 999999;

SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 39;
```

which returned a single row and this profile:

```
'starting', 0.000106
'Opening tables', 0.000017
'System lock', 0.000005
'Table lock', 0.000014
'init', 0.000033
'optimizing', 0.000009
'statistics', 0.000013
'preparing', 0.000010
'executing', 0.000003
'Sending data', 0.126565
'end', 0.000007
'query end', 0.000004
'freeing items', 0.000053
'logging slow query', 0.000002
'cleaning up', 0.000005
```

Since the index is not usable, `MySQL` needs to perform the full table scan.

`0.126565` seconds are the time from the beginning of the execution (the time the first row was read) and the end on the execution (the time the last row was sent to the client).

This last row is at the very end of the table and it took a long time to find and send it.

`P. S.` Edited to remove the downvote :)

Comment: I'm using version 5.1.35.  And why would the index not be usable?

Comment: `@Jack M.`: my post explains why.

Comment: As I was reading it, it hadn't updated to include your edits, and now I can't seem to actually change it to an up-vote.

Comment: `@Jack M.`: remove the downvote first by clicking on the downarrow, then upvote.

Comment: "Vote too old to be changed, unless this answer is edited".  Yell at Jeff.  =-]

Comment: `@Jack M.`: I will. Try now :)

Comment: That's done, but now I can't change to an up-vote, still.  *shakes fist*

Comment: `@Jack M.`: nevermind, I've already done my rep cap for the day. It was the fact that your downvote made my score not round that irritated me most :)

Comment: It's a known bug (can't change downvote into upvote even after edit). Here's one to compensate, though I would've upvoted you anyway for the great answer.

Comment: If given time is a time elapsed from previous step then what's standing for:
'starting', 0.000106

Answer (score -9):

I think you transfer lot of data an a slow network connection.

Instead of select * do only select the columns which you really need.

If your table contains large textfields which you want to show in the result you can use substring to only transfer the first few characters/words of the text.

Some clients support compression of the result packets. Maybe yxou want to have a look on that.

Comment: This is running from localhost, returning only 100 results, and most results are 1 email address and one name.  Not large amounts of data, not a slow connections.