# diagnose and avoid MySQL cpu spikes

Tags: mysql

I am trying to discover why mysqld sometimes saturates the cpu and stalls.

I suspect it's something to do with updating indices or other such maintenance. I'd like to prove this hypothesis and look at options for avoiding it.

Here's the situation. I have dozens of tables, but based on activity, it seems there are at least two which consistently suffer from this. Let's call them `Big` and `Small`. `Big` contains about 6,000 rows totalling 1Mb (so not all that big) and `Small` has dozens of rows, about 50 bytes each. `Big` has a foreign key to `Small` (InnoDB, on delete cascade, not null).

There are two situations which seem to trigger the problem: a) a modification of a `Big.small_id` value, or b) the addition of a row to `Small`.

I would intuitively expect a) to be pretty damn quick, `O(log(size of Big))` and b) to be virtually instant because `Small` is so small and none of `Big`'s references to it have changed.

In each case the subsequent SELECT takes something like twenty **gigacycles** (!); the one after that takes no time at all. There are other tables which have foreign keys to both of these tables, but there are all fairly small and I assume they're not responsible for this spike.

How can I find out which indices MySQL is updating and how long each takes?

Or, if it isn't updating indices, how can I find out what else is taking so long?

Finally, can I set up mysqld to give a lower thread priority to this work, and/or temporarily disable the index to allow non-indexed (non-blocking) selects to happen concurrently with the maintenance task?

Answer (score 2):

Another diagnostic tool you might look at is [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/).  It's basically a wrapper for `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, but it provides quicker access to this data when you see a problem happening and don't have a mysql cli handy/available to run commands.

Also, have a look at: [MySQL "Sending data" horribly slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445597/mysql-sending-data-horribly-slow)

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better solution, but I previously had a situation where I needed to find what db/table was using lots of CPU occasionally.  I cronjobbed a "show processlist" and had the output appended to a rolling log.  I was doing this every second and kept a rolling window of 6 hours.

Comment: SHOW PROCESSLIST shows that a query is in the "Sending data" state for a long time. It's not more descriptive than that. I doubt that's a fair label because I'm on localhost, transmisison should not be a bottleneck. Where do I go from here? Thanks